# Upload multiple files with one shortcut in PhpStorm

Tags: bash, phpstorm

How can I upload a selection of files with a single shortcut in PhpStorm?

Ideally it uses the PhpStorm Deployment-mechanism, - but all answers are welcome. Such as making a bash-file, that scp's the files over (which is then executed using PhpStorm).

I'm looking for a way, where I can simply press something like: `CMD` + `OPT` + `CTRL` + `J` - and then it uploads all these marked files.

My project have below-shown structure. I've marked the files I would like to be able to upload with an (x):

```
project
|- subfolder
   |- subsubfolder
      |- assets
      |  |- css (x)
      |  |- js (x)
      |  |- admin (x)
      |  |- img
      |
      |- foo.php
      |- bar.php
      |- style.css (x)
      |- bundle.js (x)
      |- other.php
      |- other-1.php
```

---

**Attempt1**

I've already tried the: **"Upload changed files automatically to the default server" == "Always|On explicit save..."** - and it's quite magically. But if the setup isn't right - then it can mess up badly.

Comment: If it's a fixed file list ... then I suggest to write a bash/cmd/powershell script that will process such upload for you. You can then create an External Tools entry in PhpStorm to execute that command. Once it's created and working you can assign any custom shortcut to that entry in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`.

Comment: If it **has to be** built-in Deployment functionality ... then it's not really possible to do with one shortcut. The best you can do is this: 1) create a custom scope where you list ALL wanted files 2) In Project View panel switch to using that scope (so only those files are listed) 3) Once ready to deploy -- focus Project View with that scope active, select all files and hit the usual Upload shortcut. As you may see it's not convenient and easy to make an error.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. This is how I did it. FINALLY!!! I've been looking for this for years (no exaggeration). I just got too annoyed with it now, that I dived down into the suggestion @LazyOne came with ( <3 ).

I using PhpStorm v. 2020 and I'm on a Mac.

---

### Step 1 - Install SSHPASS

This was the first hurdle. There are a couple of different taps out there. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62623099/1766219) worked for me:

`brew install hudochenkov/sshpass/sshpass`

This is necessary to avoid getting prompted for the password whenever the `scp`-command is executed.

---

### Step 2 - Get SCP to work from a terminal

It's annoying to debug from inside PhpStorm. So I would suggest starting in the terminal, getting a SCP-command to work. It relative to soooo many things, so it might differ from one host to another.

Please note that SCP is using SSH to copy files, to SSH should be enabled for this to work.

Here's a command that works for me:

`sshpass -p 'mypassword' scp style.css app.js SERVER_USER@SERVER_IP:public_html/wp-content/themes/my_theme_name/`

This copies two files to the given destination.

> Why I'm not using a SSH-key instead?

I'm on a server where there is a master-user, that I can add my ssh-key to - so that can access the server. But I can't do that for the individual instances.

---

### Step 3 - Make a shell-script

I made a script called `uploader.sh` and added this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p 'mypassword' scp myfile.css anotherfile.js athirdfile.php SERVER_USER@SERVER_IP:public_html/wp-content/themes/my_theme_name/
```

Then I went to 'Run' >> 'Edit configurations' and add a new Shell-file.

**Note!!** Remember to uncheck 'Execute in terminal'. The reason being that it's nice to be able to just keep working whereever you are. And if you execute it in the terminal, then the cursor will finish in the terminal. If it's unchecked, then it doesn't do that.

Here you can see my configuration:

[image: upload multiple files in PHPStorm script]

---

### Step 4 - Run and test

Now go tho 'Run' >> 'Run' and choose the one you just added. Then you should see a window like this:

[image: result uploading multiple files with one command]

And to run latest 'Run' again, you can simply press `CMD` + `r`.

BAM!

---

### Step 5 - Add uploader.sh to .gitignore

Now the password to your server is stored in clean-text in a file on your machine. It's bad for security purposed. So if you're coding a backend for nuclear launches, then you probably shouldn't do this.

But remember to add the `uploader.sh` file to your `.gitignore`-file to avoid uploading it to the repo.

### Useful resources

- [How to use sshpass, to pass a password to `scp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955428/1766219).